# How to use an element of Ruby Array as Hash key?

Tags: ruby

### So let me reform this question:

I have two hashes I'm comparing against. At some point in my code I get a response such as..

```
@moves = {:wm01 => {:a1=>"O", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"O", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "}
```

This corresponds to an answer key hash...

```
@anskey={
    :wm01=>":c3",:wm02=>":c2",:wm03=>":c1",:wm04=>":b3",:wm05=>":b1",:wm06=>":a3",:wm07=>":a2",:wm08=>":a1",
    :wm09=>":a3",:wm10=>":c1",:wm11=>":a1",:wm12=>":c3",:wm13=>":c3",:wm14=>":c1",:wm15=>":c3",:wm16=>":a1",
    :wm17=>":b1",:wm18=>":b2",:wm19=>":b3",:wm20=>":a2",:wm21=>":b2",:wm22=>":b2",:wm23=>":c2",:wm24=>":b2"
  }
```

in this case I need to iterate @anskey where @moves.keys == @anskey.keys

(hmmm. I may have just answered my own question)

and then set....

```
my_answer_is = @anskey.value
```

Hope this is clearer.

### Original "question" below:

It's been a long day and I'm getting screen fatigue...

I have this...

```
str = [:wm24]
```

want to say...

```
@anskey[:wm24]
```

this is wrong..

```
@anskey[str]
```

what is right?

```
@anskey[?]
```

Comment: Frack your question :-) If you can't be bothered spending some time formulating an intelligent question, why should we help you? In the time it took you to enter that diatribe, you probably could have come up with a better title. I would suggest less rant and more calm in future, no-one really cares how frustrated you are.

Comment: What is @anskey, and what are you trying to get?

Comment: @paxdiablo the question is fine (very clear to me), he's apparently just having title issues. I've definitely cussed a lot of software out in my time.

Comment: Oh, I just realized I know @thefonso IRL :P If you're coming to 8LU tomorrow, come say hi ^_^

Comment: @paxdiablo my frustration was directed at the title field when attempting to create a title that would pass the fields pass requirements. I could respond to your very positive comments...but I'll refrain. However I will say that -much- time was spent creating multiple titles that never passed the title fields reqs, hence creating frustration. One day I'll be an awesome programmer that never gets frustrated by code problems after 12hrs of straight work...but by then, humanity will all be cyborgs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass it the first element from the array like this:

```
@anskey[str.first]
```

Or if you want to access an element based on its index (position in the array), you count up from zero. So in this case:

```
@anskey[str[0]]
```

Comment: Thanks Jedi Master Josh! Was hoping to get there today :( but may have to wait till next friday. Stayed up way to late last night.